# wasm_bindgen Problem with async fn in Rust

Tags: asynchronous, rust

So i struggle for some time because the Rust Compiler won't give me sufficient information about this Problem.

I try to compile a Rust lib into a wasm module with `wasm-pack build --out-dir [dir]` but every time i try to compile it gives me this error:

```
error[E0597]: `*arg0` does not live long enough
  --> src/lib.rs:10:1
   |
10 | #[wasm_bindgen]
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^-
   | |             |
   | |             `*arg0` dropped here while still borrowed
   | borrowed value does not live long enough
   | argument requires that `*arg0` is borrowed for `'static`

error: aborting due to previous error
```

Code:

```
use wasm_bindgen::prelude::*;
use wasm_bindgen_futures::JsFuture;
use js_sys;

#[wasm_bindgen]
pub async fn calculation(x:i32,y:i32) -> Result<JsValue,JsValue>{
    let f = js_sys::Promise::resolve(&JsValue::from_str("Mama"));
    let p = wasm_bindgen_futures::JsFuture::from(f).await?;
    Ok((p))
}


#[wasm_bindgen]
pub async fn picture_calculation(picture: &[u8]) -> JsValue{

    JsValue::from_str("Hello")
}
```

Comment: solved yet? im facing this problem, my arg0 is &str